# Wrote two Android apps with Eclipse. Can't install both at the same time?

Tags: android, installation, signature

I wrote two completely different applications for Android, and although learning Android was a bigger pain in the butt than I would have liked, they both work nicely. Unless I try to install them both at the same time.

Android thinks they are the same app! I have no idea why. Both are signed. Android wants me to uninstall app A before I can install app B. It's not like they have the same name or anything. They do use the same package name, but the activity names are different. Does the package name have to be different?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes. The packages are supposed to be specific to your program / 'company' so keep them that way.

Answer (score 1):

The have to have different package names.  No two apps in the android marketplace can have the same package name.  Just change the package name and you should be good.  You can guarentee unique package nams for your app simply with using com.developername.appname naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Android identifies different applications by their different package names.  If an application has the same package name as another in the market (or on the device), it will be unable to tell which one is the correct package to modify / delete / start, and thusly requires all applications to have different package names.

Answer (score 0):

The packages must have different names and they must be signed with two different keys.